# decrease count of length when delete in Angular

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io

I have following html code to display length count

```
 <span *ngIf="Products?.length" class="badge badge-danger ml-1 text-dark">
            {{Products.length}} 
 </span>
```

.ts file is

```
  Products: [];

  socket = io.connect('http://134.209.150.112:3000');

  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    public data: ApiService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.getProducts();
    this.socket.on('productAdded', () => {
      this.getProducts();
    })
  }

  getProducts() {
    this.data.getcustomize().subscribe((res) => {
      this.Products = res['products'];
    })
  }
```

delete .ts file is

```
onDelete(productId: string){
    this.service.deleteCart(productId).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.service.getcustomize().subscribe((res) => {
        this.Products = res['products'];
          })
      })
}
```

I am able to delete file but count is not decreased. Need to refresh for that. I am trying to decrease count at a time when i delete.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203224/my-view-does-not-update-when-i-change-my-array-in-ngfor/53203848#53203848

Comment: You can use separate field for length and decrease it by `separateValueForLength--;`

Comment: you have subscription inside another subscription. Avoid it. @Kurt Hamilton example is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert your nested subscribe to a `switchMap` instead.

```js
onDelete(productId: string) {
  this.service.deleteCart(productId).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.service.getcustomize())
  ).subscribe(res => {
    this.Products = res['products'];
  });
```

Nested subscriptions are bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

How about using separate field for length

```
productsLength: number;
getProducts() {
  this.data.getcustomize().subscribe((res) => {
    this.Products = res['products'];
    this.productsLength = res['products'].length;
  })
}
```

And when deleting decrease it by one

```
onDelete(productId: string) {
  this.service.deleteCart(productId).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    this.service.getcustomize().subscribe((res) => {
      this.Products = res['products'];
      this.productsLength--;
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: This is true, but why would you do that?