# My angular template don't refresh after subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I'm using angular 17 and I'm getting data from my API but after reciving it the template doesn't update and I ca't show my data.

My component service where I'm doint my request to the server:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { APIBASEURL } from 'app/constants.config';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashboardService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${APIBASEURL}/dashboard/links`)
  }


}
```

My component where I subscribe to the previous method:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { FuseCardComponent } from '@fuse/components/card';
import { DashboardService } from './dashboard.service';
import { Subject, takeUntil } from 'rxjs';
import { MatIconModule, MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// import { CustomIconDirective } from './custom-icon.directive';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input'; 
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { UserService } from 'app/core/user/user.service';
import { User } from 'app/core/user/user.types';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  standalone: true,
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  imports: [CommonModule, FuseCardComponent, MatIconModule, MatInputModule, MatSlideToggleModule, MatButtonModule],
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
})


export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  data: any;

  private unsubscribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();


  constructor(
    private dashboardService: DashboardService,
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private _userService: UserService,

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // Subscribe to the dashboard service
    this.dashboardService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log('subscribe: ', this.data);
    });

    console.log('after: ', this.data)
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribeAll.next(null);
    this.unsubscribeAll.complete();
  }

}
```

After that in the template I just show up my data but it's always empty.

And if I look at the devtool in the console I'll see that at first the second console log i'ts showing first and then the second one with the data correctly.

After a lot of research I found if I do this:
`this.data = this.dashboardService.getData()`
instead of subscribin and then in the template putting async
`@if(data | async; as data)` this works but I want to know why subscribing it's not working.

Let you know that I'm new in angular and this is my first website.

I tried usgin the second method as I said but I want to know why the first one is not working

Comment: You should edit your question and add the (relevant) code for the template.

Comment: In general, it is better to use the AsyncPipe instead of subscribing manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnPush change detection will only update the view when an @Input value changes or an observable bound in the template emits.

To fix your issue, you could manually call detectChanges as suggested by @Jacopo Sciampi.

Or, you could use default change detection.

Or you could keep your data as observable and use the async pipe, which is what I find to usually be the simplest code:

```js
export class DashboardComponent {

  data$: Observable<any> = this.dashboardService.getData();

  constructor(
    private dashboardService: DashboardService,
    private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
    private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private _userService: UserService,
  ) { }

}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">

  <p> My data </p>
  <pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>

</ng-container>
```

Notice that without an explicit subscription in the template, you no longer need to manage unsubscribing, so you no longer need the `Subject`, nor `ngOnDestroy`. If you initialize the `data$` when you declare it, you also don't need `ngOnInit`.

---

Also, if you do decide you need some explicit subscriptions (*usually in components this is not necessary*), you can leverage the new [`takeUntilDestroyed()`](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed) operator:

```js
private sub = this.dashboardService.getData().pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe(
   data => this.data = data
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view is not updating automatically because of the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

In order to update the view without using the `async` pipe in the template you can use the `ChangeDetectionRef`:

```
 constructor(
    ...
    private _cdr: ChangeDetectionRef
  ) { }
```

And then:

```
 this.dashboardService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.data = data;
      this._cdr.detectChanges(); // <----
      console.log('subscribe: ', this.data);
    });
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203224/my-view-does-not-update-when-i-change-my-array-in-ngfor/53203848#53203848)

#### PS:

*In general, it is better to use the AsyncPipe instead of subscribing manually.*

It is NOT. It always depends on what you're trying to achieve.